# get a range of bytes from a bytearray

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, regex

I have a bytearray:

```
b_arr = b'\\xff\\x02\\x04\\x01\\x00\\x02'
```

I want to get the last 3 bytes as:

```
out = 'b\\x01\\x00\\x02'
```

I've tried:

```
m = re.search("rb'\\x02\\x04'(.*)",b_arr)
```

But get a `TypeError: TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, that's a `bytes` object, not a `bytearray` object and it has hex escape codes in it.  This will retrieve the last three hex escape codes via string slicing:

```
>>> b_arr = b'\\xff\\x02\\x04\\x01\\x00\\x02'
>>> b_arr[-3*4:]
b'\\x01\\x00\\x02'
```

The regular expression would work if quoted correctly:

```
>>> b_arr = b'\\xff\\x02\\x04\\x01\\x00\\x02'
>>> import re
>>> m = re.search(rb'\\x02\\x04(.*)',b_arr)
>>> m.group(1)
b'\\x01\\x00\\x02'
```